# How do users vote on Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion

I sometimes don't understand how people decide to upvote or downvote a question on SO. The theory is that the OP needs to do a bit of research first before asking, and if they still get stuck after enough effort, they may ask the question on Stackoverflow.

Then, if the question is a common problem encountered by many programmers, and is well-structured, it gets "favourited" by other users. However, I sometimes see very general questions asked in a single line and they still get tens or even hundreds of votes. An example would be this question ([How to sum array of numbers in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-members-in-ruby)). While there are many cases where if the user doesn't show exactly where they're stuck, the first comment they receive is 'what have you tried?'!

So how come some questions asked in a single line can get that many votes?

Comment: Always look at the age of such posts, the stack overflow culture was very different a few years ago

Comment: It took nearly 4 years and over 66k views for that question to accumulate so many votes.

Comment: whoever has downvoted this question, they're seriously **retarded**. If I can't ask this type of question on `meta.stackoverflow`, then I don't know what can be asked!

Answer (score 5):

The linked question is very old. The culture of a site like Stack Overflow inevitably changes, and this is a symptom of that. The question is clear and well-written, and in 2009 that was what was expected. Now in 2013, more research effort is required. In 2017, it'll be different again. It is impossible to judge yesterday's questions by the standards of today.

Additionally, a question will tend to get upvotes (for better or worse) if it personally helps the voter. So a question that is useful to a large number of people will tend to collect upvotes over the years despite its quality.

Comment: @JoshMein sorry about the edit reject, I was editing it at the same time

Comment: Ahh no big deal. I dont care about the 2 points